# MS Power BI reports takes long time to refresh

Tags: powerbi

There is a PBIX file(abc.pbix) that has a query to fetches 4 months of data from a table. This PBIX file report has been published and shared with certain users from a user(user_1). 
Now I want to publish & share the same with another user(user_2)

I have open the abc.pbix file in Power BI desktop and sign in with user_2 to publish. I have published, but now the Refresh is taking a long time. Its been 1 day, still the refresh is happening.
how to overcome and resolve? please suggest on this?

Comment: Where are you refreshing the data from?

Comment: Refreshing from POWER BI desktop.

Comment: Sorry I meant what data source

Comment: SQL server which in cloud is the data store.